# Binding to ObservableCollection causing memory leak

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I am binding an ObservableCollection to a an AreaSeries. The OC gets updated frequently and each time it is updated it uses more memory, without the old data being garbage collected so it just keeps growing.

Here is my XAML:

```
<charting:AreaSeries Name="areaSeries" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data}"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Y}" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=X}" TransitionDuration="00:00:00">
    <charting:AreaSeries.DataPointStyle>
        <Style TargetType="charting:AreaDataPoint">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkBlue"/>
        </Style>
    </charting:AreaSeries.DataPointStyle>
</charting:AreaSeries>
```

`Data` is an ObservableCollection of type `PointViewModel`:

```
public ObservableCollection<PointViewModel> Data
{
    get { return m_data; }
}
```

`PointViewModel` implements `ViewModelBase`:

```
public class PointViewModel : ViewModelBase
```

and `ViewModelBase` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable`.

Here is how `Data` is updated:

```
int xPos = 0;
foreach (float fv in m_fHistogramValues)
{
    if (m_data.Count - 1 < xPos)
        m_data.Add(new PointViewModel(m_fHistogramXValues[xPos], fv, false));
    else
    {
        m_data[xPos].X = m_fHistogramXValues[xPos];
        m_data[xPos].Y = fv;
    }

    xPos++;
}
```

Everything I can find online says to make sure IPropertyNotified is implemented to avoid memory leaks, but I think it is implemented correctly. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you ever clear your m_data? As I can see you only add to it.

Comment: I tried adding m_data.Clear() before the foreach loop, but it didn't make a difference. The `PointViewModel`s are only supposed to get added the first time through (it adds 256 items to the OC), each subsequent time is supposed to just replace the X and Y properties.

Comment: Does your program crash with OutOfMemoryException, or what does exactly happen?

Comment: No, the memory usage just keeps growing. It goes from 200MB (which is about what it should be) to up to 5GB if I let it.

Comment: Presumably if it got large enough it would eventually crash (there is quite a bit of RAM available).

Comment: Did you debug your foreach loop to see if your values are properly replaced and if your m_data doesn't get bigger? How about m_fHistogramValues?

Comment: Do you use MEF or does `PointViewModel` contain any other event handlers?

Comment: I figured out the problem. The Data property getter of the ViewModel was creating a new OC and copying Data from the Model to the new one and returning that: `return new ObservableCollection<PointViewModel>(m_Model.Data);` and so apparently the old OC was never getting erased. Now instead of creating a new OC each time I just return the same OC with the data replaced: `return m_Model.Data;`. Thanks for all your comments.